# Inside onMapReady, Picasso doesn't load image the first time

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, picasso

Picasso is being used across the app and it works fine except when I'm using it inside onMapReady to load marker images. Here's the code:

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        mMap = googleMap;

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(getMarkerBitmapFromView1(strImage,strNameplace)))
                    .position(lnglng));
         }

private Bitmap getMarkerBitmapFromView1(String strImage, String strNameplace) {

        final View customMarkerView = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.marker_custom, null);
        markerImageView = customMarkerView.findViewById(R.id.ivan);

        final Target target = new Target() {
            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                markerImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }

            @Override
            public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

            }
        };

        markerImageView.setTag(target);

        Picasso.with(this)
                .load(strImage)
                .into(target);

        customMarkerView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        customMarkerView.layout(0, 0, customMarkerView.getMeasuredWidth(), customMarkerView.getMeasuredHeight());
        customMarkerView.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(customMarkerView.getMeasuredWidth(), customMarkerView.getMeasuredHeight(),
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        Drawable drawable = customMarkerView.getBackground();
        if (drawable != null)
            drawable.draw(canvas);
        customMarkerView.draw(canvas);
        return returnedBitmap;
    }
```

How can I achieve loading the images in first run?